# Instantaneous velocity on R studio

Tags: r, velocity

(Rstudio) suppose I have a data set of:

```
# Circle  X    Y
1 A      21   8 
2 A      32   17
3 A      23   32
4 B      22   4
5 B      43   12
6 C      12   4
.....
```

I need to find the instantaneous velocity of each circle at each time frame.
For line 1 is the starting point so the velocity is 0, and the formula I want to achieve for each circle's (X, Y) coordinates is sqrt(((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)/2)) where the x2 and x1 is from the previous line (e.g. line 1 & line 2, Line 2 & line 3). the final result I want to have is as below:

```
# Circle  X    Y  Instant velocity
1 A      21   8     0
2 A      32   17   sqrt(((32-21)^2 + (17-8)^2)/2))
3 A      23   32   sqrt(((23-32)^2 + (32-17)^2)/2))
4 B      22   4     0
5 B      43   12   sqrt(((43-22)^2 + (12-4)^2)/2))
6 C      12   4     0
.....
```

Could anyone help me in achieving this on Rstudio???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one more `)` than `(` in your code example, which makes me a bit confused about where the `/2` goes, but if you verify my syntax something like this should work:

```
library(dplyr) 
your_data %>%
  group_by(Circle) %>%
  mutate(
    instant_velocity = coalesce(sqrt(((x - lag(x))^2 + (y - lag(y))^2)/2), 0)
  )
```